# how to create separate class for addOnGesturePerformedListener

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

hai all this is my code

```
private GestureLibrary gLib;
private static final String TAG = "com.hascode.android.gesture";
protected static final TextWatcher watcher = null;

private EditText et1;
private EditText et2, et;

// int dec = et.getText().toString().length()-1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et = et1;
    gLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);

    // glip1 = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures1);

    if (!gLib.load()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "could not load gesture library");
        finish();
    }
    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(handleGestureListener);
}

/**
 * our gesture listener
 */
private OnGesturePerformedListener handleGestureListener = new OnGesturePerformedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureView,
            Gesture gesture) {

        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLib.recognize(gesture);
        // ArrayList<Prediction> predictions1 = glip1.recognize(gesture);
        Toast.makeText(gestureinput.this,
                predictions.get(0).name + " " + predictions.get(0).score,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // one prediction needed
        if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 2.0) {
            String prediction = predictions.get(0).name;
            // checking prediction

            if (prediction.equals("A")) {
                // and action
                et.append("A");

                // et.getText().insert(et.getSelectionStart(), "A");
            }
    }
    }
};
```

}

now i need to create separate class for gesture listener (OnGesturePerformedListener) please any one guide me how to create new class like thisand how to call that class for oncreate method please guide me i'm new to android and java..

```
private OnGesturePerformedListener handleGestureListener = new OnGesturePerformedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureView,
            Gesture gesture) {

        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLib.recognize(gesture);
        // ArrayList<Prediction> predictions1 = glip1.recognize(gesture);
        Toast.makeText(gestureinput.this,
                predictions.get(0).name + " " + predictions.get(0).score,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // one prediction needed
        if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 2.0) {
            String prediction = predictions.get(0).name;
            // checking prediction

            if (prediction.equals("A")) {
                // and action
                et.append("A");

                // et.getText().insert(et.getSelectionStart(), "A");
            }
    }
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
class MyGestureHandler implements OnGesturePerformedListener{
    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureView,
            Gesture gesture) {

        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLib.recognize(gesture);
        // ArrayList<Prediction> predictions1 = glip1.recognize(gesture);
        Toast.makeText(gestureinput.this,
                predictions.get(0).name + " " + predictions.get(0).score,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // one prediction needed
        if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 2.0) {
            String prediction = predictions.get(0).name;
            // checking prediction

            if (prediction.equals("A")) {
                // and action
                et.append("A");

                // et.getText().insert(et.getSelectionStart(), "A");
            }
    }     
}
```

and create object like this way.

```
MyGestureHandler myHandler = new MyGestureHandler();
gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(myHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply its working cool but i can't able  to access ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLib.recognize(gesture);   and et.append("A"); these local variables are in main activity ...how can i access that GestureLibrary and edit text in this class ..

Comment: create this class as inner class or declare gLib as public

Comment: and you should accept or give +1 /-1 point when answer or question are useful or good or / off topic/ vague etc.